# Orchard partial deployment to production

Tags: deployment, orchardcms, production-environment

I'm currently looking into Orchard CMS to use for my new projects. With other CMS systems that I use, information related to new functionality is sometimes stored in the database (data, configuration, language items). Deploying this functionality to a production site (already running with it's own database ect.) is done using packages which "install" the data in the production database.

How is this done using Orchard? Or is all functionality file-based and can it be easily deployed using XCopy when a site is already running in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an import/export feature that you can use to transfer data and settings between Orchard instances.